# Is there a penalty kick mode on fifa 15?

Tags: fifa-15

Is there a penalty kick mode for fifa 15, or do I have to go to kick off and wait for the match to finish as a draw?

Answer (score 1):

You can practise them, but there is not a mode for just playing them like in the older versions.

Comment: Can't we practice them on training grounds?

Answer (score -1):

You can practice them in Training Grounds.